# python mysql select return only first row of table, not all

Tags: python, mysql

im dealing with strage problem and this is like this:

this query should return all of my table:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="A", passwd="B", db="X")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
cursor.fetchall()
for row in cursor:
print row
```

for loop should print all rows in cursor but it will only print the first one.
it seems cursor is filled with first row only.

is there anything that i missed here?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the output of cursor.fetchall() into a variable. Like

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="A", passwd="B", db="X")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try **limit**:

```
cursor.execute("select * from mytable limit 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="A", passwd="B", db="X")
cursor = db.cursor()
for row in cursor.execute("select * from mytable"):
    print row
```

Comment: it returns an error "for row in cursor.execute("select * from mytable"):
TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 0):

you need a dic and save the result here

```
dic={}
cursor.execute("select * from table")
dic['table']=cursor.fetchall()
for row in range(len(dic['table'])):
    print dic['table'][row]
```

and if you need print any colum

```
print dic['table'][row]['colum']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way to use the `.fetchall()` method. Use `cursor.stored_results()` and then do a `fetchall()` on the results to perform this task, like this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="A", passwd="B", db="X")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from mytable")
results = cursor.stored_results()
for result in results:
    print result.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. My mistake was that after inserting new row in the table I didn't commit the result. So you should add db.commit() after INSERT command.

Answer (score 0):

i know its been very long time since, but i didnt find this answer anywhere else and thought it might help.

cursor.execute("SELECT top 1 * FROM my_table")